# Is there a way to use post/pre-increment (++i / i++) in PHP without using loops?

Tags: php

For example

```
for($i=0; $i<100; $i++){
    array_push($something, $i);
}
```

Is there a command  that does this without using a loop?

Edit: PHP Example

Comment: `i=99; ++i;`, maybe?

Comment: Yes. It's a normal operator.

Comment: You don't need a loop to use preincrement/postincrement. But what is it you're actually trying to do?

Comment: *"Is there a command that does this without using a loop?"* -- that does what? The [increment/decrement operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) operate over a variable. They don't require anything else. And btw, the code you wrote is not valid PHP. The PHP variables are prefixed with the dollar (`$`) symbol. For example, `$i=0; $i++; echo($i);` will display `1`.

Comment: You can use those operators anywhere you want.  What are you actually trying to do?  What did you try and how is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

No need for loops for increment/decrement in PHP, more details here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the components of a for loop:

```
for(<initial statement>; <condition expression>; <statement executed at end of loop>){}
```

Meaning if you wanted to, you could do:

```
for(apples="good"; isRaining(); doDoubleRainbow()) { }
```

Apples gets assigned to "good" on loop start.  At the end of every loop, doDoubleRainbow() gets called and in order to determine whether or not to leave the loop, it calls isRaining().  Does this make sense?  No, though you could do it.  There is no rule that says you have to have your loop in the form:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++) { }
```

In this sense, i++ just fits the parameter "statement executed at end of loop".  It just so happens to ensure that the loop eventually ends, but you're of course free to call i++ entirely on its own and it does the same thing it does in your loop for every loop cycle.

Hope that helps!